# Understanding object literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

While practising few examples , I encountered the following example :

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
var object = {};
object[foo] = 'value';
alert(object[bar]);
```

where two objects foo and bar are created . I am not getting how alert(object[bar]); is "value".
Whats the link here between foo and bar.

Also, a slight variation would give the output as "undefined" as the example below.

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
var object = {};
object["foo"] = 'value';
alert(object[bar]);
```

By default , the `[]` notation can use the strings right , arent `["some_property"]` and `[some_property]` the same?

Comment: The link between `foo` and `bar` is that they both yield the same result when cast to a string (which all property keys are)

Comment: "*arent `["some_property"]` and `[some_property]` the same?*" - No.

Comment: Btw, how an `Object` is converted to a primitive is regulated by the `valueOf` or `toString` methods (the former takes precedence over the latter in case both are defined).

Comment: @LUH3417: Not always, depends on the context.

Comment: @Felix Please name such a context. I am eager to learn.

Comment: @LUH3417: `''+foo` will call `foo.valueOf` first, but `String(foo)` will call `foo.toString` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using square bracket notation, anything inside the square brackets is converted into a string. Then that string is used to look for a property called the same thing.

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
var object = {};

object[foo] = 'value';
// foo is an object, so it's automatically turned into the string "[object Object]"
// so the above code is equivalent to `object["[object Object]"] = 'value';`

alert(object[bar]);
// bar is also an object, so is converted into the same string
// the above code is also equivalent to `alert(object["[object Object]"]);` which of course accesses that same value

var blah = "not blah";
object.blah = 1;
object["blah"] = 1;

object[blah];
// a variable is used.
// therefore the value of that variable is what the assessor is looking for, not the name of the variable.
// so the above code is equivalent to `object["not blah"];`.
```

Answer (score 0):

An object's keys can only be strings*, so when you access an object's property using value which is not a string, it gets converted to a string.

In ECMAScript 6 you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is similar to objects, but you can use any value as a key. Example:

```
const foo = {unique_prop: 1}
const bar = {unique_prop: 2}
const map = new Map()
map.set(foo, 'value')
console.log(map.get(bar)) // undefined
```

---

* In ECMAScript 6 you can also use [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), but that's not relevant here.